# How to change the last layer of pretrained PyTorch model?

Tags: pytorch

I need my pretrained model to return the second last layer's output, in order to feed this to a Vector Database.

The tutorial I followed had done this:

```
model = models.resnet18(weights=weights)
model.fc = nn.Identity()
```

But the model I trained had the last layer as a nn.Linear layer which outputs 45 classes from 512 features.

```
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
```

I need to get the second last layer's output i.e. 512 dimension vector.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new model from the layers that you want to use, e.g. to drop the last layer:

`vec_model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])`

Full code:

```py
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn as nn
from torchinfo import summary

model = models.resnet18()
layers = list(model.children())[:-1]
layers.append(nn.Flatten())
vec_model = nn.Sequential(*layers)
summary(vec_model, input_size=(16, 3, 224, 224), row_settings=("depth", "ascii_only"))
```

Output:

```
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
Sequential                               [16, 512]                 --
+ Conv2d: 1-1                            [16, 64, 112, 112]        9,408
+ BatchNorm2d: 1-2                       [16, 64, 112, 112]        128
+ ReLU: 1-3                              [16, 64, 112, 112]        --
+ MaxPool2d: 1-4                         [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
+ Sequential: 1-5                        [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-1                   [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-1                  [16, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-2             [16, 64, 56, 56]          128
|    |    + ReLU: 3-3                    [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-4                  [16, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-5             [16, 64, 56, 56]          128
|    |    + ReLU: 3-6                    [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-2                   [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-7                  [16, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-8             [16, 64, 56, 56]          128
|    |    + ReLU: 3-9                    [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-10                 [16, 64, 56, 56]          36,864
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-11            [16, 64, 56, 56]          128
|    |    + ReLU: 3-12                   [16, 64, 56, 56]          --
+ Sequential: 1-6                        [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-3                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-13                 [16, 128, 28, 28]         73,728
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-14            [16, 128, 28, 28]         256
|    |    + ReLU: 3-15                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-16                 [16, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-17            [16, 128, 28, 28]         256
|    |    + Sequential: 3-18             [16, 128, 28, 28]         8,448
|    |    + ReLU: 3-19                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-4                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-20                 [16, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-21            [16, 128, 28, 28]         256
|    |    + ReLU: 3-22                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-23                 [16, 128, 28, 28]         147,456
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-24            [16, 128, 28, 28]         256
|    |    + ReLU: 3-25                   [16, 128, 28, 28]         --
+ Sequential: 1-7                        [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-5                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-26                 [16, 256, 14, 14]         294,912
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-27            [16, 256, 14, 14]         512
|    |    + ReLU: 3-28                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-29                 [16, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-30            [16, 256, 14, 14]         512
|    |    + Sequential: 3-31             [16, 256, 14, 14]         33,280
|    |    + ReLU: 3-32                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-6                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-33                 [16, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-34            [16, 256, 14, 14]         512
|    |    + ReLU: 3-35                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-36                 [16, 256, 14, 14]         589,824
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-37            [16, 256, 14, 14]         512
|    |    + ReLU: 3-38                   [16, 256, 14, 14]         --
+ Sequential: 1-8                        [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-7                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-39                 [16, 512, 7, 7]           1,179,648
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-40            [16, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
|    |    + ReLU: 3-41                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-42                 [16, 512, 7, 7]           2,359,296
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-43            [16, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
|    |    + Sequential: 3-44             [16, 512, 7, 7]           132,096
|    |    + ReLU: 3-45                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    + BasicBlock: 2-8                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-46                 [16, 512, 7, 7]           2,359,296
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-47            [16, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
|    |    + ReLU: 3-48                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
|    |    + Conv2d: 3-49                 [16, 512, 7, 7]           2,359,296
|    |    + BatchNorm2d: 3-50            [16, 512, 7, 7]           1,024
|    |    + ReLU: 3-51                   [16, 512, 7, 7]           --
+ AdaptiveAvgPool2d: 1-9                 [16, 512, 1, 1]           --
+ Flatten: 1-10                          [16, 512]                 --
==========================================================================================
Total params: 11,176,512
Trainable params: 11,176,512
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (G): 29.02
==========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 9.63
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 635.83
Params size (MB): 44.71
Estimated Total Size (MB): 690.17
==========================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to see it is to just print your model out. Like this: `print(model)`, in the case of resnet18 you can see the last layer has in_features of 512, so it means second last layer's output has 512 neurons. In this case you can also use `model.fc.in_features` to get 512.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `sequential`:

```
import torch.nn as nn

second_last_layer = nn.Sequential(*list(model_ft.children())[:-2])

# pass your data through the second last layer to get its output
second_last_output = second_last_layer(your_data)
```